# how to empty the recycle bin in SharePoint using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0, sharepoint-online

How to empty the recycle bin in SharePoint using SharePoint Online Management PowerShell?

I'm facing an error

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

[image]

Comment: If this is your whole code, I'd say the problem is that most of your variables are uninitialized and only used in one place. How could that work...

Comment: In particular, the first command uses `$Credential`, and the second one `$Cred`. The error message implies that `$Cred` is `$null

Comment: Do you want to use SPO PowerShell only or are you open to use other free tools as well? Check: [SharePoint Online: Empty Recycle Bin using PnP PowerShell](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/03/29/empty-sharepoint-online-recycle-bin-using-pnp-powershell/). Let me know if this works for you.